# Zend_Date::sub() and ISO_8601 calculating hour difference wrong

Tags: php, zend-framework, iso8601, zend-date

I want to calculate time difference between two Zend_Date objects (for countdown calculator):

```
$now = new Zend_Date($now_datetime, Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
$end= new Zend_Date($end_datetime, Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
echo $now->getIso(); 
echo $end->getIso();

$expires=array();
$expires['expired']=false;
if($end->isEarlier($now)){
   $expires['expired']=true;
   return $expires;
}

$dif=$end->sub($now);
$expires['days']=($dif->getDay()->toValue()/(60*60*24));
$expires['hours']=($dif->getHour()->toValue()/(60*60));
$expires['minutes'] = $dif->getMinute()->toValue()/60;
$expires['seconds'] = $dif->getSecond()->toValue();

var_dump($expires);
```

For $now_datetime ='**2012-06-30 01:01:01**' and $end_datetime='**2012-06-30 23:59:59**', the result is

```
2012-06-30T01:01:01+02:00
2012-06-30T23:59:59+02:00
//array
'expired' => boolean false
'days' => int 0
'hours' => int 22
'minutes' => int 58
'seconds' => int 58
```

and it is OK.

But for For $now_datetime ='**2012-06-30 00:01:01**' and $end_datetime='**2012-06-30 23:59:59**', the result is

```
2012-06-30T00:01:01+02:00
2012-06-30T23:59:59+02:00
//array
'expired' => boolean false
'days' => int 1
'hours' => int -1
'minutes' => int 58
'seconds' => int 58
```

and it is NOT OK. I expect 'hours' to be **23**, not **-1** ?!

I am running MAMP with php 5.3, Zend_Framework 1.10.
What is wrong with that? ISO_8601 is used for MySQL 'datetime' data and I don't wanto to change to mktime()...

Comment: What does $dif->getIso() return?

Comment: your code works perfect for me.. i am using zf 1.11 php5.3 and zend community server.. may be some default setting of your mamp is hampering your result...

Comment: @ccKep - $dif->getIso() returns '1970-01-02T00:58:58+01:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

in your index.php.. it will work fine..